# Xamarin app doesn't correctly load data for app while in Germany

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a super odd bug which has stumped us.

In short we have developed an app in Xamarin and this contains a calendar setup and each time you swipe to a day it looks for data and loads the schedule for that day. The data is minimal, it's simply a heading, description text and there are maybe 10 events max per day. The server setup is a Microsoft Azure server, likely in Europe.

This works 100% while we're in South Africa.

The issue is that the users in Germany are having issues where they reach a day and there is no data. They then scroll to the next day and there is no data, but if they return to the first then the data is there. So it is loading but not like the users in South Africa. Oddly they then close the app and if they open they get the same issue.

Any guidance as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Do you have any code, any output from a log file, a stracktrace? Anything? As the post is currently written, it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: Have you tried changing a device timezone to Germany's TZ to see if that might be the cause of it? Or can you connect to a European Azure instance?

Comment: Okay thats crazy - I change my device to Germany timezone and I get the issue occurring. Why would that be? Great comment and insight by the way!

Comment: Seconding @Demitrian's comment, and also suggest posting the request payload for the calendar schedule API call.